# Join two tables and show null in result set if match not found between joined tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join, left-join

My table structure looks like this:

Table A:

```
AID       AName
1         AAA
2         BBB
```

Table B:

```
BID       AID    
10         1      
10         2    
11         2
```

In table B, AID is foreign key to primary key of table A. BID 10 belongs to AID 1 and AID 2 and BID 11 belongs to AID 2 only and not AID 1. I need result like this:

Expected Result:

```
BID    AID    AName
10       1    AAA 
10       2    BBB
Null     1    AAA
11       2    BBB
```

Table A is base table. Since in table B, for BID 11, it does not have record for AID 1, so the new result set should return NUll.
I am not able to accomplish it using joins. How can I achieve it?

Comment: TableB looks like a many-to-many join table between TableA and some other table, `BID` should be a foreign key of this other table. Where is that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of `TableA` to the distinct `BID`s of `TableB` to get all combinations of `AID` and `BID` and then a `LEFT` join to `TableB`:

```
SELECT b.BID, a.AID, a.AName
FROM TableA a CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT BID FROM TableB) t
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.BID = t.BID AND b.AID = a.AID
ORDER BY t.BID, a.AID
```

See the [demo](http://SELECT%20b.BID,%20a.AID,%20a.AName%20FROM%20TableA%20a%20CROSS%20JOIN%20(SELECT%20DISTINCT%20BID%20FROM%20TableB)%20t%20LEFT%20JOIN%20TableB%20b%20ON%20b.BID%20=%20t.BID%20AND%20b.AID%20=%20a.AID%20ORDER%20BY%20t.BID,%20a.AID).